# Will all my contact details get delete if I reset my Lumia 525?

Tags: backup, nokia-lumia-525, reset

Unfortunately I delete some inbuilt apps like Calender, Podcast, BatterySaver etc in my Lumia 525. So I was not able to open any apps and not able to open email accounts in my mobile. I didn't find any way to resolve this problem so I plan to reset my phone. I have taken backup already but my doubt is, If I reset my phone will all my contact details get delete?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How did you manage to delete those apps? Calendar and Podcasts don't have an uninstall option, and Extras doesn't even show up in the app list.

Comment: @Indrek Take a look at the image added. First three are **@{Microsoft.MSBatterySaver**, **@{Microsoft.Calendar**, **@{Microsoft.Podcast**.

Comment: I can't accept you edit without opening the question again. Unfortunately it was pretty much the same problem. You are asking about the same thing in rhea related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your contacts are all backed up on cloud by default (I think). to double check, go to pc login to outlook and check you contacts are there....then there shouldn't be any problems when you reset your phone...just make sure your apps+settings, text messages and photos+videos are backed up. settings>backup.